# HttpClient not present at run time

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, rest, httpclient

I am trying to create a rest client. I am using Spring. I have instantiated `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`, which uses `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` inside. Maven compilation is Ok, but when I run the project I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient.`

Furthermore, when I place the mouse pointer on top of the import of HttpClient, I get `sun.net.www.http.HttpClient`, which is in rt.jar, instead of getting `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`. I have checked that HttpClient truly does not exist in any other package. I know that I can find `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` in other artifacts, such as

```
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
<version>4.0-alpha3</version>
```

However, I am not sure whether this should be right, since Spring itself does not seem to resort to this (I cannot see it does when I check the dependency hierarchy in the pom file).

In any case, I wonder why an import such as `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` should resort to `sun.net.www.http.HttpClient`. I guess that the fact that the latter is in rt.jar is related to HttpClient not being available at run time.
If you want to check about all this, this is my pom file, it is quite simple:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks a lot.

**Edit:**
The code is quite simple, you just need to instantiate the class `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`. There is more code, but you only need this to obtain the exception.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Client {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Client.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: You should show the code that causes the issue and also add   `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  </dependency>` in your pom.

Comment: what you are pasting is not your pom file, please review your post and fix it properly, otherwise giving an anwser will not be possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have the *HttpClient* declared in your maven project dependencies, thus it will not be on your Classpath, thus not available at runtime.

Just add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to your pom file, and it should then be available on the classpath. (You should not need to specify the version as it's inherited from the Spring Boot parent pom).

As far as why you see  `sun.net.www.http.HttpClient` that looks to just be your **IDE** incorrectly assuming the type of `HttpClient` because it doesn't have access to the correct one as it's not on your classpath.